# Comparing 3 columns for difference in numbers

Tags: excel, formula

Cells C1,D1,E1's values are "69, 69, Not In Console"  <--- This is considered healthy

Cells C2,D2,E1's values are "55, 54, Not In Console" <--- This is Need Attention

Cells C3,D3,E3's values are "54, Not In Console, 55" <--- This is Need Attention

Cells C4,D4,E4's values are "33, Not In Console, 33" <--- This is considered Healthy

The value presented are connections made from 3 different programs in a specific time range. Now if any of these two numbers are different that tells me there is an issue with one of the programs. They should always be the same. The "Not In Console" just says that particular program is not installed which is fine. I need to find the difference between the cells containing numbers while ignoring the cells containing "Not In Console"

Here Is my formula that Tried but its labeling everything as Need Attention

```
=IF(AND(C2=D2,E2="Not In Console",OR(C2=E2,D2="Not In Console",OR(D2=E2,C2="Not In Console"))),"Healthy","Attention")
```

Comment: will c always be a number or can it also be the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIF()

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(C1:E1,MAX(C1:E1))+COUNTIF(C1:E1,"Not In Console")=3,"Healthy","Not Healthy")
```

[image]

Comment: That is the best thing I've seen all week. Your awesome huge relief.

Comment: Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer you used.

Answer (score 1):

```
={IF(SUM(EXACT(SUBSTITUTE(C1:E1,"Not in Console",MAX(C1:E1)),MAX(C1:E1))*1)=3,"Healthy", "Not Healthy")}
```

3 instances of `Not in Console` are considered `Healthy` here

---

If you just use the below formula, you can work with `TRUE`, `FALSE` results. You can have your header be `HEALTHY?`so the output is simple to interpret

```
={EXACT(SUBSTITUTE(C1:E1,"Not in Console",MAX(C1:E1)),MAX(C1:E1))}
```

---

> Array formulas must be entered with  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  +  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>
>    +  <kbd>ENTER</kbd>  and it should also be stated these are
>   more invasive, thus, less effecient than other solutions offered here.

Comment: I did not think of `MAX()` and I have stolen it to use in my latest edit. :)

Comment: Oh my. How the tables have turned @ScottCraner